# apt-fast upgrade not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt-fast

I installed apt-fast but it not working.. when i command in terminal `sudo apt-fast upgrade` but it gives some exception error.. like this..

```
 Exception: [AbstractOptionHandler.cc:69] errorCode=28 We encountered a problem while processing the option '--max-connection-per-server'.
  -> [OptionHandlerImpl.cc:187] errorCode=1 max-connection-per-server must be between 1 and 16.
Usage:
 -x, --max-connection-per-server=NUM The maximum number of connections to one
                              server for each download.

                              Possible Values: 1-16
                              Default: 1
                              Tags: #basic, #http, #ftp
```

What can i do?..

Comment: Did you set `--max-connection-per-server` or `-X` to a value greater than 16?

Comment: No,i set nothing. i don`t know the value. @muru

Answer (score 1):

I think it is caused by your setting of `Maximum number of connections` in `apt-fast` greater than the max number `apt-get` or `aptitude`(depends on which one you use) allowed.

The solution is easy:

1. `sudo vim /etc/apt-fast.conf`
2. change `_MAXNUM=100`(in my case it's set to 100）to `_MAXNUM=16` or some number less than 16